# Calling MATLAB through Shell with Python Script Issues

Tags: python, bash, matlab, shell, scripting

I'm having an issue with this call I can't seem to resolve:

```
os.system('matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r \"processFates;dlmwrite(\'' + FWHM + ' ' + volume      + ' ' + key + ' ' + str(numTrials) + '\", min_timing)\"')
```

FWHM, volume, key are all strings. I keep getting the error of an extra ) but it seems like I need all of them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this with some values:

```
>>> FWHM, volume, key, numTrials, min_timing = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
>>> print('matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r \"processFates;dlmwrite(\'' + FWHM + ' ' + volume      + ' ' + key + ' ' + str(numTrials) + '\", min_timing)\"')
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "processFates;dlmwrite('a b c d", min_timing)"
```

See that double quote after the `d`? That should probably be a single quote. Also, the min_timing you're passing is the literal string `min_timing`, not the variable you're expecting.

Using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system` you can avoid some of these problems with escaping by not relying on the shell and passing the arguments as strings directly:

```
command = "processFates; dlmwrite('%s %s %s %s', %s)" % (FWHM, volume, key, numTrials, min_timing)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['matlab', '-nodisplay', '-nosplash', '-r', command])
```

Comment: Ah I see okay. But matlab still doesn't seem to be executing dlmwrite still.

Comment: [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) suggests that your syntax of the dlmwrite command is not right, you should need to have commas between the parameters, and quote the string parameters... I just indicated the problems with the shell syntax. I don't use matlab, so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: Okay. So the first one you fixed is actually giving me the result I needed without using the subprocess module. Matlab would process my parameters but not tell me it did anything (which is weird) but it works.

Thanks!